# Can I add a function that queries the database and uses its results, inside a mysql transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have this error:
Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in X

The error appears in a transaction because, and only after I added inside it a function that does a database query inside, with this structure:

```
  $conectarDB->beginTransaction();

  [some queries]

  $empleado = traerNombreEmpleados($codigo);

  [some more queries that use $empleado]

  $ok = $conectarDB->commit();
```

The function in question is a simple one that the only thing it does is a database query and return a result:

```
function traerNombreEmpleados($codigo) {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
  $conectarDB = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DATABASE.'; charset=utf8', USER, PASS); 
  $conectarDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $x = $conectarDB->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE codigo = ?");
    $x->bindParam(1, $codigo);
    $x->execute();
    $nombreItem = $x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $nombreItem['nombre'];
}
```

**Is there any way to circumvent this issue? Or I just need not to use transactions for this?**

Comment: It looks like you are creating a separate PDO connection each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work, but you'd need `$conectarDB` from the outer scope inside the function.

You could try sending it as a parameter to the function.

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
  $conectarDB = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.'; dbname='.DATABASE.'; charset=utf8', USER, PASS); 
  $conectarDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $conectarDB->beginTransaction();

  [some queries]

  $empleado = traerNombreEmpleados($conectarDb, $codigo);

  [some more queries that use $empleado]

  $ok = $conectarDB->commit();

function traerNombreEmpleados($conectarDb, $codigo) {
  
    $x = $conectarDB->prepare("SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE codigo = ?");
    $x->bindParam(1, $codigo);
    $x->execute();
    $nombreItem = $x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $nombreItem['nombre'];
}
```